# Grafana fails to run from Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana

I'm trying to run Grafana with Prometheus using docker compose.

However I keep getting the following error from Graphana container:

`service init failed: html/template: pattern matches no files: /usr/share/grafana/public/emails/*.html, emails/*.txt`

Here's the content of `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.3"

volumes:
    prometheus_data: {}
    grafana_data: {}

services:
        prometheus:
                image: prom/prometheus:latest
                ports:
                        - "9090:9090"
                expose:
                        - 9090
                volumes:
                        - ./infrastructure/config/prometheus/:/etc/prometheus/
                        - prometheus_data:/prometheus
                command:
                        - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
                        - '--storage.tsdb.retention.time=1y'

        graphana:
                image: grafana/grafana:latest
                user: '472'
                volumes:
                        - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
                        - ./infrastructure/config/grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
                        - ./infrastructure/config/grafana/datasource.yml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yml
                ports:
                        - 3000:3000
                links:
                        - prometheus
```

As for the content of `grafana.ini` and `datasource.yml` files I'm using the default Grafana configuration files that are [provided](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/tree/main/conf) in its official Github repository.

The answer [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/15021#issuecomment-457499273) suggests that it can be resolved by setting the correct permissions to grafana config folder. However, I tried giving full permission (with `chmod -R 777` command) to the `./infrastructure/config/grafana` folder and it didn't resolve the issue.

If anyone can provide any help on how to solve this problem it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why you are mounting defaults as grafana.ini, when defaults are already in the container? Why you just don't use grafana.ini to modify defaults? Apparently it is failing on the email template configuration - https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/c2754eb9cc948111e6134e99e599202d2092600a/conf/defaults.ini#L612 and apparently you didn't provide those templates.

Comment: @JanGaraj I tried removing the grafana.ini mounting and the error disappeared. Thank you!
However, I checked the email template configuration first and it looked fine, exactly the same as in the line you referenced.

And what if I'll have to make some changes to the grafana.ini file? Then I need to keep it locally and mount it, right?

Answer (score 1):

USE THIS in your docker_compose

```
grafana:
    hostname: 'grafana'
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    restart: always
    tmpfs:
      - /run
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./infrastructure/config/grafana/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana  /grafana.ini
      - ./infrastructure/config/grafana/datasource.yml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yml
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```